# web3.py " filter not found "

Tags: events, web3.py, bsc, binance, filters

im using web3.py v5.19 in my project and we are on BSC mainnet
also i use bsc urls recommended in site to connect to nodes
this is my code to get events :

```
block_filter1 = contract.events.validatorSuggested.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
for event in filter.get_new_entries():
                if event.event == 'validatorSuggested' : 
                   ...
```

but after a while i got this error :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/web3/_utils/filters.py", line 160, in get_new_entries
    log_entries = self._filter_valid_entries(self.eth_module.get_filter_changes(self.filter_id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str, params, error_formatters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/web3/manager.py", line 158, in request_blocking
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'filter not found'}
```

as i searched , the problem comes from '' stateless '' nodes which clear filters .
what should i do exactly in order to solve this problem and receive events ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I switched to a websocket rpc instead of an HTTP one and it started to work that way

Comment: great! this helped me a lot. I'll have to do more test, but I think your answer should be accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Developer advocate at Chainstack here!

The error you're seeing, `ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'filter not found'}`, is a common issue developers encounter when working with filters on EVM-compatible blockchains like BNB Smart Chain. This error arises when the system cannot locate the specified filter ID during a query.

There are several reasons why you might encounter this error:

> The filter is created on the blockchain node so this can cause situations.

1. **Filter Expiration**: Filters are not permanent. They can expire after a certain period of inactivity, usually around 5 minutes. Once a filter expires, querying it will result in the "Filter Not Found" error.
2. **Node Restarts**: If the blockchain node is restarted, filters created before the restart might be lost.
3. **State Pruning**: Some nodes might prune or remove older states, including filters, to save space.
4. **Manual Deletion**: Filters can be manually removed using methods like [eth_uninstallFilter](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-uninstallfilter).

Given your scenario and the details provided, here are some solutions you can implement to handle the "Filter Not Found" error effectively:

1. **Immediate Change Retrieval with Error Handling**:

   - After setting up a filter, fetch the changes immediately.
   - Implement error handling to handle the potential "Filter Not Found" error.

   ```py
   from web3 import Web3
   import time

   # Initialize web3 connection
   node_url = "YOUR_BSC_ENDPOINT"
   web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(node_url))

   def get_new_blocks():
       try:
           blocks_filter = web3.eth.filter('latest')
           return blocks_filter
       except Exception as e:
           print(e)

   blocks = get_new_blocks()
   filter_id = blocks.filter_id

   try:
       changes = web3.eth.get_filter_changes(filter_id)
       # Process the changes accordingly
   except ValueError as error:
       if "filter not found" in str(error).lower():
           print("The filter seems to have expired or is non-existent. Consider recreating it.")
       else:
           print(f"Encountered an error: {error}")
   ```
2. **Automated Filter Recreation**: If a filter expires or is not found, consider automating its recreation within your error-handling logic.
3. **Persistent Filter Monitoring**: Set up a loop continuously monitoring the filter for changes. If the filter expires or is removed, you can detect it immediately and take corrective action.
4. **Use Event Logs Instead of Filters**: Instead of relying solely on filters, you can use the [eth_getLogs](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-getlogs) method to fetch historical data. This is especially useful for past events or transactions.
5. **Backup Filters on Multiple Nodes**: Create the same filter on multiple nodes to ensure redundancy. If one node fails or the filter is removed, you can still retrieve data from another node.
6. **Regularly Refresh Filters**: Proactively refresh or recreate filters to ensure they remain active and reduce the chances of encountering the error.
7. **Implement Comprehensive Logging**: Incorporate detailed logging into your application to diagnose issues quickly and understand their root causes.

Hope this helps! There is an entire guide on the Chainstack dev portal!

- [Understanding Ethereum's "Filter not found" error and how to fix it](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/understanding-ethereums-filter-not-found-error-and-how-to-fix-it)

Feel free to reach out as well!